# getElementbyID for loading music player data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently building a music player with HTML5 audio functions API and before I start coding the audio functionality of the player I'd like to use `getElementbyID` and `onClick` functions to display results in a separate `div`s by class or ID.
I want to use something like inline HTML metadata attached to a link or button that will display the metadata in a separate `div` container.

So something like this for example:

```
<button src="mysong.mp3" artist="artist" title="name of the song"
 album="name of album" cover="albumcover.jpg" onClick="load metadata and play music"
>
```

And each section would have its own `div` for displaying the metadata from the link/button that was clicked.

So the output would go to something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="artist"></div>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="album"></div>
  <div id="html5 audio controllers"></div>
  <div class="googleads"></div>
</div>
```

I am new to coding and I learn better with examples. So can someone please help with this? It's literally the last loading object of my PWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
function addSong (song) {
  if (song && song.dataset) {
    const { src, artist, title, album, cover } = song.dataset;
    document.getElementById("cover").innerHTML = cover;
    document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = artist;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("album").innerHTML = album;
  }
}
```

```html
<button data-src="mysong.mp3" data-artist="artist" data-title="name of the song" data-album="name of album" data-cover="albumcover.jpg" onClick="addSong(this);">Add Song</button>

<div id="metadata">
  <div id="cover"></div>
  <div id="artist"></div>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="album"></div>
  <div id="html5-audio-controllers"></div>
  <div class="googleads"></div>
</div>
```

What I’m doing here is using the data attribute of the button to pass in the information which will be used to populate the metadata containers. Semantically this would be the recommended way to put that information into the button element itself. Alternatively, you could pass a JSON object to the onClick handler instead, in which case you would not need the data attributes.

I also changed the ID for the audio controllers, as you would not want to use spaces there.

Comment: thank you for the detailed feedback and explanation on how this code works. I actually understood it as you explained... thank you very much.